# Servlet can't access from Smartphone or IE

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I have a problem to access my Servlet page from Smartphone or explorer.

I open a servlet page in Eclipse.

I can access it in Chrome using same address and local computer but I can't access it from Explorer of local computer and Smartphone.

This is a my servlet code:

```
package awst.moon.BTServlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


/**
 * Servlet implementation class BTServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/BTServlet")
public class BTServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BTServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Called Get");
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //doGet(request, response);
        System.out.println("Called Post");

    }

}
```

This is a web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>BTservlet</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>BTservlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>BTservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>awst.moon.BTServlet.BTServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BTservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/BTservlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Tomcat Version : 7.0 
Jre : jre 1.8.0_45
Explorer Version : IE11

I need your help. 
Thank you.

Some information is added:

My url is "http://223.194.7.143:8888/BTservlet/BTservlet"

I could not access any browser except chrome in local computer.

Android and Iphone also cannot access that address and error message is "connection time out".

This is a part of logcat.

```
    07-09 01:31:20.176: D/IOP_DB_BT(2113): db_query_add_key: key KEY_DIR_ALL, value *
07-09 01:31:20.186: D/IOP_DB_BT(2113): db_query_execute: result 1
07-09 01:31:20.186: D/bt_vendor(2113): op for 7
07-09 01:31:20.186: D/BluetoothSocket(1803): connect(), SocketState: INIT, mPfd: {ParcelFileDescriptor: FileDescriptor[717]}
07-09 01:31:20.186: V/AlarmManager(829): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
07-09 01:31:20.196: V/AlarmManager(829): trigger ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP or RTC_WAKEUP
07-09 01:31:20.216: D/bt_upio(2113): proc btwrite assertion
07-09 01:31:20.236: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.316: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.316: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.326: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.326: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.326: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.326: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.326: I/SensorManagerA(4423): getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
07-09 01:31:20.336: E/Sensors(829): Acc old sensor_state 0, new sensor_state : 1 en : 1
07-09 01:31:20.336: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.336: D/SensorManager(4423): registerListener :: 0, K330 3-axis Accelerometer, 0, 0,  
07-09 01:31:20.336: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:20.796: D/SSRMv2:Monitor(829): SIOP:: AP = 400, Prev AP = 400, Duration = 10088, PST = 400
07-09 01:31:21.146: I/SensorManagerA(4423): getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
07-09 01:31:21.146: E/Sensors(829): Acc old sensor_state 1, new sensor_state : 0 en : 0
07-09 01:31:21.146: D/SensorManager(4423): unregisterListener ::   
07-09 01:31:21.156: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:21.216: D/bt_vendor(2113): op for 7
07-09 01:31:21.366: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(829): ContainerId: 0
07-09 01:31:22.216: D/bt_upio(2113): ..proc_btwrite_timeout..
07-09 01:31:22.686: E/SMD(346): DCD OFF
07-09 01:31:23.366: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(829): ContainerId: 0
07-09 01:31:23.726: I/chromium(21332): [INFO:top_sites_impl.cc(926)]  VLOG NotifyTopSitesChanged
07-09 01:31:23.806: E/Watchdog(829): !@Sync 4825
07-09 01:31:25.336: E/bt-btif(2113): DISCOVERY_COMP_EVT slot id:606, failed to find channle,                                       status:1, scn:0
07-09 01:31:25.346: D/WearableBluetooth(1803): onSocketReady returned, closing socket
07-09 01:31:25.376: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(829): ContainerId: 0
07-09 01:31:25.376: I/ServiceKeeper(829): In getpackagename pid = 829 uid = 1000 package name = android
07-09 01:31:25.686: E/SMD(346): DCD OFF
07-09 01:31:27.366: D/EnterpriseDeviceManager(829): ContainerId: 0
07-09 01:31:28.686: E/SMD(346): DCD OFF
```

Comment: what is the url you use to access your servlet?

Comment: Do you see an error in IE or on you smartphone? what is it?

Comment: Explain more about the error and provide the URL you are using on your phone

Comment: Thank you comment. 
I think a problem that is tomcat.
I can not start tomcat of eclipse and tomcat properties at the same time.

Comment: I cannot found reason. So, I did reinstall tomcat 8.0.
After that, no problem.